# Visual Studio Community (2015) Web Templates Missing

Tags: visual-studio

After months of using Visual Studio Community (2015) Web Templates just disappeared.

When I try to create new project whole Web category is missing.

When I open old projects and for example try to add New Item, items are missing as well.

I've tried:

devenv.exe /installvstemplates

Reinstalling VS

Removing Web Development Tools (and adding them)

Starting VS on different Windows Account (and user)

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you ever figured out this template issue?

Comment: Windows Reinstall... :|